# How does a server check if incoming connections are secure?

Tags: ssl

1. In secure socket communication, how does the server (e.g. google.com) check whether the incoming connection is secure?

   Detail: consider a web browser that downloads the HTTPS page - in that case, it checks the server's certificate and puts it in the trust store. On the server side, how does it check whether the connection is secure?
2. Why are certificate chains passed to a client instead of a single certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A connection isn't magically secure. It needs to be negotiated and established. The SSL/TLS protocol details a series of steps that both parties need to follow in order to negotiate a secure connection. So, the server can be sure a connection is "secure" because it has just undergone a series of steps in concert with the client to establish said connection securely. If the client didn't follow along properly, the connection can't be established.

You also need to differentiate between *encrypted* and *authenticated*. The SSL/TLS protocol details how to *encrypt* a connection, which the server can be assured about. The server does *not* check any certificate of the client. The server cannot *authenticate* the client. The certificate check is one-sided, the client only checks the server's certificate. The server can be assured that messages sent to whoever it's talking to cannot be intercepted or manipulated, but it has absolutely no clue who that someone it's talking to actually is.

(A server *can* require a client to have a certificate as well, but in practice this is rarely used, because clients don't typically have any certificate.)

> Why are certificate chains passed to a client instead of a single certificate?

Because the security of certificates is predicated on previously established trust. The client needs to already trust some root certificate that has signed the server's certificate. Oftentimes these days there are more steps between a root certificate and the server certificate. The root will have signed an intermediate certificate which may have signed another intermediate which has then signed the server's certificate. Since the client often can't be expected to have all those intermediate certificates in its trust store already, they're send together with the server certificate. The client can verify the chain back to the root, which it does trust.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. In secure socket communication, how does the server (e.g. google.com) check whether the incoming connection is secure?

The incoming connection *isn't* secure until both peers have negotiated an SSL handshake, including the certificates and a cipher suite.

> Detail: consider a web browser that downloads the HTTPS page - in that case, it checks the server's certificate and puts it in the trust store.

Only if the user tells it to. I don't see the relevance.

> On the server side, how does it check whether the connection is secure?

See above.

> 2. Why are certificate chains passed to a client instead of a single certificate?

Because the signed certificate by itself is meaningless. It needs to be accompanied by a signer chain, and the client need to trust someone in that chain.